# How can I echo comments with most secure way in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I'm trying to code a wordpress theme that totally based on user comments. I really need to make my comment textarea really safe. I coded this function against XSS attacks;

```
function antixss($comment) {


return sanitize_textarea_field(esc_html(esc_textarea($comment)));

}

add_filter('comment_text_rss', 'antixss');
add_filter('get_comment_text', 'antixss');
add_filter('get_comment_excerpt', 'antixss');
```

I'm calling comments with: `comment_text()` function.

I don't know whats the best way to do it.

Without that function above, even alert(1); is working...

How do I make it more secure?

Comment: Have you got an example of a XSS attack that is printing on your page? Are you trying to solve a problem that is already handled by the base wordpress?

Comment: Are you saying current core implementation is not secure? If yes then you need to talk to core team and it should be fixed in the core.